# "<Application-defined or object-defined error> Error 1004"

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple for-next to fill some labels on a userform but can not figure out why a keep getting a " Error 1004" When I type the Contr.Caption the .Caption function is missing?

```
Dim Control_Name As String
Dim DSlot As Long
Dim DLName As Long
Dim Contr As Control

With Worksheets("apartments").Range("depositslot")
    DSlot = .Find("Slot").Row + 1
    DLName = .Find("Last").Column
End With

For Each Contr In Layout.Controls
    If TypeName(Contr) = "Label" Then
        Control_Name = Mid(Contr.Name, 1, 6)
            If Control_Name = "LBName" Then
                Contr.Caption = Worksheets("apartments").Range(DSlot, DLName).Value
                DSlot = DSlot + 1
            End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Caution that `.Find` 'remembers' all of the options that were used last it was run through, even on the worksheet. Optional parameters like `LookAt:=(xlPart or xlWhole), MatchCase:=(True or False), SearchFormat:=(True or False)` shouldn't be left to default to whatever was used last.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your line saying:

```
Contr.Caption = Worksheets("apartments").Range(DSlot, DLName).Value
```

should be

```
Contr.Caption = Worksheets("apartments").Cells(DSlot, DLName).Value
```

The `Range` property does not accept two parameters of type `Long`.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the "Range" object by "Cells", since you have references of "Row, Column". You should have something like this:

```
Contr.Caption = Worksheets("apartments").Cells(DSlot, DLName).Value
```